# Javascript Scroll Function to add class at different points depending on type of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, scroll

I have a simple javascript function for a fixed sidebar navigation that fixes the sidebar when the viewer has scrolled past a certain point of the page. This is my first post and I am new to javascript.

This issue now is that for pages that have a banner, the class needs to be added at a different scroll point.

Below is what I have now, that works, but it only uses the second function. Meaning, my pages without a banner, the side bar becomes fixed too late.

```
$(function() {
var div = $(".sidebar-wrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 147) {
        div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
    } else {
        div.removeClass("fixed-product-nav");
    }
});
});
$(function() {
var div = $(".sidebar-wrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 263) {
        div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
    } else {
        div.removeClass("fixed-product-nav");
    }
});
});
```

I did try a way that works with if statements, but now I need it to not be page id specific.  I tried the [id^="mbItem"] selector, but it wouldn't work since technically both pages have the id in them.  See below.

```
$(function() {
var div = $(".sidebar-wrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (div.hasClass('mk-main-wrapper')) {
        if (scroll > 147) {
        div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
        } else {
        div.removeClass("fixed-product-nav");
        }
    } else {
        if (scroll > 263) {
            div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
        } else {
            div.removeClass("fixed-product-nav");
        }
    }
});
});
```

Below is my HTML structure for a page WITHOUT banner.

```
<div id="mk-page-id-171" class="theme-page-wrapper mk-main-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
```

Below is my HTML structure for a page WITH banner.

```
<div id="mk-page-id-171" class="theme-page-wrapper mk-main-wrapper">
    <...HTML...>
<div class="theme-page-wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
```

So the Page ID is still on both pages, but it is the parent of sidebar-wrapper for only WITHOUT banner.

Hopefully this makes sense, I'm working from within a WordPress theme.

I feel like I'm close, but maybe now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your HTML but I think that you're targeting the wrong div in the second piece you've posted.
"Pages without a banner are inside a mk-main-wrapper div" this means that you don't need to search if .sidebar-wrapper has the class but most probably it's parent (or it's parent's parent, depending on your HTML code). Something like this:

```
   $(function() {
var div = $(".sidebar-wrapper");
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (div.parent().hasClass('mk-main-wrapper')) {
        if (scroll > 147) {
        div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
        } else {
        div.removeClass("fixed-product-nav");
        }
    } else {
        if (scroll > 263) {
            div.addClass("fixed-product-nav");
        } else {
            div.removeClass("fixed-product-nav");
        }
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it actually didn't work. I updated the post with an option that I actually got to work, but not quite. I also added my html.

Comment: I created a simple working example for your html markup. Check it here :http://jsfiddle.net/z3Lduw5e/

Comment: (It's just to show the working logic you'll need to use. You'll need to remove the .each() method and add your own events.)

Comment: I understand how that works, but when I apply it to my page, it still doesn't work.  I made a new JSFiddle with updated and more accurate html and you can see how it doesn't quite work for some reason.  http://jsfiddle.net/z3Lduw5e/2/

Comment: It doesn't work because you're targeting the wrong div again. You should not be targeting the parent, but the parent's parent. There you go: https://jsfiddle.net/yb46v7qo/1/